# Write output to a text file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, file-io

I've compared two files using the following code:

```
Compare-Object $(Get-Content c:\user\documents\List1.txt) $(Get-Content c:\user\documents\List2.txt)
```

How can I write the output of this to a new text file? I've tried using an echo command, but I don't really understand the syntax.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Use the `Out-File` cmdlet

```
 Compare-Object ... | Out-File C:\filename.txt
```

Optionally, add `-Encoding utf8` to `Out-File` as the default encoding is not really ideal for many uses.

Comment: What about STDOUT (info) vs. STDERR (error) messages?  Will they both go to the out-file?

Answer (score 24):

The simplest way is to just redirect the output, like so:

```
Compare-Object $(Get-Content c:\user\documents\List1.txt) $(Get-Content c:\user\documents\List2.txt) > c:\user\documents\diff_output.txt
```

`>` will cause the output file to be overwritten if it already exists.
`>>` will append new text to the end of the output file if it already exists.

Comment: This is the cmd / dos method. For powershell I think Out-File is a much better habit to get into

Comment: @AthomSfere, I agree.  I'm still learning PowerShell, and old habits die hard. :)

Comment: This is also the Unix way, if you are using windows by force, this is the way.

Comment: Maybe not so outdated? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 7):

Another way this could be accomplished is by using the `Start-Transcript` and `Stop-Transcript` commands, respectively before and after command execution. This would capture the entire session including commands.

[Start-Transcript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-6)

[Stop-Transcript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/stop-transcript?view=powershell-6)

For this particular case `Out-File` is probably your best bet though.