# Write output of PS2 script to textfile

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have the following script:

```
Get-ChildItem $rootPath -Recurse | 
    Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | 
    Where-Object {(Get-ChildItem $_.FullName | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer}|  Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count) -gt 0} |
    ForEach-Object{

        $files = Get-ChildItem $_.FullName

        $props = @{
            Path = $_.FullName
            Size = "{0:N0}" -f (($files | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} |  Measure-Object -Sum Length | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum))
            Count = $files | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
        }

        If ($files.Extension -match "L\d\d"){
            # These are special files and we are assuming they are alone in the directory
            # Change the path
            $props.Path = $files | Select-Object -First 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
        }

        New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $props

} | Select Path,Size,Count
```

How can I write the output to a textfile instead of to the console?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write output to text file in Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469104/write-output-to-text-file-in-powershell)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forward that to `Out-File`. For example:

```
Get-ChildItem ...
<skipped>
} | Select Path,Size,Count | Out-File "files.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things. You have other options here worth mentioning.

```
} | Select Path,Size,Count | Set-Content "files.txt"
```

`Set-Content` would also work and has the advantage of defaulting to ACSII encoding. If performance comes into play then using .Net StreamWriter will beat `Set-Content` and `Out-File` out anyway.

More importantly this code was designed to output objects. Working with that you should use `Export-CSV` to have nicely formatted output.

```
} | Select Path,Size,Count | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "files.csv"
```