# How to pipe the output of a powershell variable to text file

Tags: powershell

I have declared a powershell variable to get the packages installed on Windows 2016 server by defining a variable and i want to pipe it to a text file.

```
$jvn=Get-Command java | Select-Object Version
```

I have tried using 
`$jvn=Get-Command java | Select-Object Version | Out-File -FilePath .\jvn.txt`
but this prints on the screen , not in text file , 
i want the output in the text File as Java Version 8.0.202.26

Comment: This command you posted `$jvn=Get-Command java | Select-Object Version | Out-File -FilePath .\jvn.txt` is how you write to text file. It will not print to screen if you do this.

Comment: thanks @ArcSet for your reply , but i want add "Java" to output ,so it displays                      Java Version   
-------   
8.0.202.26

Comment: If you want to change the property name to Java Version from Version you can do this. `$jvn=Get-Command java | Select-Object @{N=’Java Version’; E={$_.Version}} | Out-File -FilePath C:\test\jvn.txt`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write output to a text file in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469104/write-output-to-a-text-file-in-powershell)

Answer (score 2):

So it sounds based on the comments that the output is happening but you want to change the name of the property from Version to Java Version.

```
Get-Command java | Select-Object @{N=’Java Version’; E={$_.Version}} | Out-File -FilePath C:\test\jvn.txt
```

The main difference from what you posted `Get-Command java | Select-Object Version | Out-File -FilePath .\jvn.txt` to the snippet above is the command Select-Object `@{N=’Java Version’; E={$_.Version}}`.

So lets break that down. We are creating a **hashtable** `@{}`.
In the hash table we are adding `N="New Name Of Property"; E="Property Value"`. The **N** is short for **Name** and the **E** is short for **Expression**.

Comment: Thanks @ArcSet for quick reply, I am new reply to Powershell.i have declared variables like $prm=Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -Computer . -Filter "vendor = 'Wolters Kluwer Financial Services'" | Select-Object Name, Vendor, Version | Out-File -FilePath D:\Software\pkg.txt , this command works fine when run in powershell not as part of script, am I missing something

Answer (score -1):

```
gcm java | foreach { $version = $_.version; "Java Version $version" } > jvn.txt
```

Comment: I have 2 variables$rgteng=Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -Computer . -Filter "vendor = 'WKFS'" | Select-Object Name, Vendor, Version | Out-File -FilePath D:\Software\pkg.txt ,  $prm=Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -Computer . -Filter "vendor = 'Wolters Kluwer Financial Services'" | Select-Object Name, Vendor, Version | Out-File -FilePath D:\Software\pkg.txt  , i want them to write to a same text file , but not happening,when run individually last o/p is print to txt file, any help here

Comment: out-file -append